# Loud feedback after HTMLAudioElement is played with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I needed a "ding" sound effect for a pomodoro app that I am building, and I found [this sound](https://freesound.org/people/Aiwha/sounds/196106/) which met my requirements. I play the sound in my application like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('ding.wav');
audio.play();
```

My problem is that, while the sound does play, after the sound finishes playing I hear loud, high pitched digital feedback for about a second.

I have not had this issue before when working with mp3s, so to ensure that it was not related to the file type, I tried using [a different `.wav` file](https://freesound.org/people/suzenako/sounds/320905/) from the same website. This file, when played in the same way is *not* followed by the feedback. Also, the timing suggests that `ding.wav` has finished playing completely before the feedback starts.

The file that is followed by the feedback does not have any feedback when played through the media player on my computer.

What would cause this kind of audio feedback, and how can I fix it? I have searched on here and looked through [the documentation for `HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), but haven't found anything useful so far. I tried lowering the `.volume` of the element to see if it was related to that, but it didn't make a difference.

If it would be helpful to actually hear what I am hearing, I can make a video and link to it, but I am not sure how else to give an example in e.g., a fiddle, because the audio file is stored locally on my computer.

## Update:

I am not sure if this makes the problem clearer, but the issue does appear to be tied to the playing of the sound rather than the audio file itself. Currently, for testing purposes, the playing of the sound is tied to the pressing of a button. If I quickly press the button 5 times in a row the full sound effect will only play fully once (i.e., if I press the button before the sound is finished, the sound is cut off and starts again), but after the sound fades out from the last button press, I will hear one loud feedback beep for each time I pressed the button (i.e., five beeps for five button presses etc.).